# Mapbox zooming and centering on page load

Tags: mapbox

I am trying to zoom and center to a point on a map.  Having tried lots of examples I can't seem to get it working.

So far i have tried to do something based on these to examples:

**link 1:**
[....mapbox.js/api/v1.6.3/l-map-class/#map-usage](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v1.6.3/l-map-class/#map-usage)

**Link 2:**
[....mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/map-center-geocoding/](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/map-center-geocoding/)

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'examples.map-i86nkdio');

var myLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);

var geoJson = [{

    type: 'Feature',
    "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [-77.03, 38.90]},
    "properties": {
        'title': 'Washington, D.C.',

        // Store the image url and caption in an array
        'images': [
            ['xxx.jpg','The U.S. Capitol after the burning of Washington during the War of 1812'],
            ['xxx.jpg','Ford\'s Theatre in the 19th century, site of the 1865 assassination of President Lincoln'],
            ['xxx.jpg','The National Cherry Blossom Festival is celebrated around the city each spring.']
        ]
    }
}, {
    type: 'Feature',
    "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [-74.00, 40.71]},
    "properties": {
        'title': 'New York City',
        'images': [
            ['xxx.jpg','Peter Minuit is credited with the purchase of the island of Manhattan in 1626.'],
            ['xxx.jpg','During the mid-19th Century, Broadway was extended the length of Manhattan.'],
            ['xxx.jpg','Times Square has the highest annual attendance rate of any tourist attraction in the world.']
        ]

    },
type: 'Feature',
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use the .setView function off of the map object to do this, same as with any other Leaflet-based map:

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'examples.map-i86nkdio').setView([10, 20], 3);
```